# Ruby on Rails 4: Deleting user triggers error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, crud

Whenever I try to delete a user I get the error: **`Couldn't find User with 'id'=8`**. The error points to a line from `application_controller.rb` in the "current_user" method: **`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users`**. "/users" is where I'm trying to redirect_to.

I don't know where I'm going wrong. I wonder if it's a `<%= javascript_include_tag ... %>` that I'm missing in the `application.html.erb file`.

**application_controller.rb**

```
def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def delete
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
 @user = User.find(params[:id]).destroy
 flash[:warning] = '#{@user.name} has been deleted.'
 redirect_to users_path
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id

            if request.referrer == login_url
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                redirect_to :back
            end             

    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email and password did not match. Please try again."
        render :new
    end
 end

 def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to :back
 end

end
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2 id="page-title"><%= @user.name %> <small>@<%= @user.username %></small>
    <div class="small pull-right"></div>
</h2>

<hr/>

<% @user.types.each do |type| %>
    <h4><small><%= type.name %></small></h4>
<% end %>

    <% if current_user == @user %> # visible to current_user
        <div class="float-right">

            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete Account', user_path, 
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete your account forever?' }, 
                    method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

If you need anymore files let me know.

I feel like this is a simple fix. Please help. And thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `find` with a non existing record id, ActiveRecord throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. You can get around this by using`find_by`, which will return `nil`. so try this in your application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Or you can just use your check more correctly by doing this

```
def current_user
 @current_user ||= (session[:user_id].present? && User.find(session[:user_id]))
end
```

The second will still raise exception if the user_id in the session is not an invalid user.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess if bug is in application controller add the following code in the destroy method of user controller:

> session[:user_id] = nil if current_user == @user

This way if you delete the current connected user, it'll be logged out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what "stack trace" means...still pretty new to RoR and programming in general.